# Remove duplicates from array but order by frequency

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array with tags, which contains every category of a certain picture. This can be Nature, Portrait, Animals, ...

An album contains, for example, 10 pictures. I load in all the tags, containing the category for each picture, so I end up with an array:

```
albumTags = ["Nature", "Animals", "Nature", "Portrait", "Architecture", "Nature", "Travel", "Travel", "Portrait", "Nature"]
```

I am now looking for a way to remove the duplicate values, but at the same time re-order the array based on the frequency of the tags. If the number of tags is equal, I want the first in the array to remain the first value (so not alphabetically, but in order of the pictures in the album). My desired outcome:

```
albumTags = ["Nature", "Portrait", "Travel", "Animals", "Architecture"]
```

How could I perform those two actions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a solution with less code.

1. `reduce` the array into a dictionary with the tag name as the key and the number of occurrences as the value.
2. `sort` it by the value (greater first).
3. `map` it back to an array by the key which holds the string.

```
let albumTags = ["Nature", "Animals", "Nature", "Portrait", "Architecture", "Nature", "Travel", "Travel", "Portrait", "Nature"]
let sortedTags = albumTags
    .reduce(into: [:], { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 })
    .sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value })
    .map({ $0.key })
```

```
// After `reduce`:
// ["Nature": 4, "Portrait": 2, "Animals": 1, "Travel": 2, "Architecture": 1]
// After `sort`:
// [(key: "Nature", value: 4), (key: "Travel", value: 2), (key: "Portrait", value: 2), (key: "Animals", value: 1), (key: "Architecture", value: 1)]
// After `map`:
// ["Nature", "Portrait", "Travel", "Animals", "Architecture"]
```

Comment: `result[string] = (previousResult[string] ?? 0) + 1` -> `result[string, default: 0] += 1`

Comment: After map : ["Nature", "Travel", "Portrait", "Architecture", "Animals"] ?

Comment: Thanks @JoshCaswell. Didn't know that was possbile.

Comment: @E.Coms What is your question?

Comment: Something I learned recently is `reduceInto` it makes the input dictionary to the reduce function mutable. So you can just do `$0[$1, default: 0] += 1` :-) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127177-reduce

Comment: The order for same occurrence is random.

Comment: @E.Coms there was no restriction set on the order for this case. Only ordering by the number of repeats. You can apply further ordering by updating the sort function.

Comment: Never mind. We have seen different requirements. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSCountedSet` for that:

```
let albumTags = ["Nature", "Animals", "Nature", "Portrait", "Architecture", "Nature", "Travel", "Travel", "Portrait", "Nature"]

let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: albumTags)
let result = countedSet.map({ $0 }).sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
    let countForFirst = countedSet.count(for: first)
    let countForSecond = countedSet.count(for: second)
    if countForFirst == countForSecond {
        //Same count, return first the one which appears before the other one in initial array
        let indexForFirst = albumTags.firstIndex(of: first as! String)!
        let indexForSecond = albumTags.firstIndex(of: second as! String)!
        return indexForFirst < indexForSecond
    } else {
        //Return the bigger one first
        return countForFirst > countForSecond
    }
}
print("Result:\n\(result)")
```

Output:

```
$>Result:
[Nature, Portrait, Travel, Animals, Architecture]
```

There is a force cast `as! String` because `NSCountedSet` has `Any` as elements (it's from `NSMutableSet`).
There is a force cast on the index calculation, but since it was taken from there, it shouldn't be an issue. You can use a `if let`/`guard let` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In a reducing way, maybe the index needing to consider:

```
var albumTags = ["Nature", "Animals", "Nature", "Portrait", "Architecture", "Nature", "Travel", "Travel", "Portrait", "Nature"]

albumTags = (albumTags.enumerated().reduce(into: [String :(Int, Int)]()){
$0[$1.element] =  (($0[$1.element]?.0 ?? 0) + 1 , $0[$1.element]?.1 ?? $1.offset)
} as [String :(Int, Int)])

.sorted {   $0.value.0 == $1.value.0 ?  $0.value.1 <  $1.value.1: $0.value.0 > $1.value.0   }

.map{$0.key}

print(albumTags)
```

Two-passes method can use `count sort` on reversed Order of array, which should be faster.

In first pass,  build an [[String]] sorted by count 0..<(max occurrence) backwards. Thus the first appearing string will be added to the last of a subArray.

The second pass is following:
flatMap of the result and reverse (in-place), which gives the right order, during which removing  any duplicates.

```
let result = albumTags.reversed().reduce(into: (([String:Int](), [[String]]()))) {
$0.0[$1]  = ($0.0[$1] ?? 0) + 1
$0.0[$1]!  > $0.1.count  ?  $0.1.append ([$1] )  : $0.1[$0.0[$1]! - 1].append($1)
}.1.flatMap{$0}.reversed()
.reduce(into: ([String](),[String:Int]())) {
       if $0.1[$1] == nil  { $0.0.append($1)  ; $0.1[$1] = 0 }
}.0



//[["Nature", "Portrait", "Travel", "Architecture", "Animals"], ["Travel", "Nature", "Portrait"], ["Nature"], ["Nature"]]

//["Nature", "Nature", "Portrait", "Nature", "Travel", "Animals", "Architecture", "Travel", "Portrait", "Nature"]

 //["Nature", "Portrait", "Travel", "Animals", "Architecture"]
```